# How to refresh ul control after update in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

This is my ul control

```
<ul id="basket" class="big-menu">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

i remove all li with this code -> `$("#basket").find('li').remove().end();`
they have been removed but don't refresh the screen until touchdown the screen in Phonegap app.

How can we solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: it didn't help in jquery-1.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
      $( '#basket' ).listview('refresh');
```